# Reading files using sys.argv in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, readfile, argv

I've been going through the book Learning Python the hard way and I got stuck in this code.

```
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv    
txt = open(filename)    
print "Here's your file %r:" % filename    
print txt.read()    
print "Type the filename again:"    

file_again = raw_input("> ")    
txt_again = open(file_again)    
print txt_again.read()
```

The problem which I'm facing is when I run the program like this: `python readingfile.py ex15.txt`
It is showing me a error that for ex15.txt( no such file or directory exist)

Now I don't know where to save the text file so that it works fine.
My code is in users>myaccount>learnpython>readingfile.py
and the text file is in desktop
I tried moving it to the learnpython folder but still it shows the same error.
So please help me out

Comment: If you move your `ex15.txt` file to `users>myaccount>learnpython>readingfile.py` it will work

Comment: Looks like you want to read about the concept of [current working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory).

Comment: Make sure you've moved the *actual file* to `learnpython`, *not* a symbolic link. If you run the `dir` command in `learnpython`, does it show `ex15.txt`?

Comment: Yes it is showing ex15.txt when i run the dir command

Comment: btw, you should switch to python 3, python 2 support has finished

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, i got my answer. It shall be in the same folder only as the code.
Now its working fine but dont what happened earlier that time.

Comment: Your code was looking for the file which was not available, The best way is to use os package for handling files.